# ansible: jump to rescue section of a block depending on boolean host variable

Tags: ansible

I want to execute a task depending on the content of a host variable in inventory. When the boolean var "cloud" is true, I want my task to fail and to execute the rescue section. For my test system, "cloud" is "false". I added debug tasks to show type and value of "cloud":

```
- name: Print value of var "cloud"
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: cloud

- name: Print value of var with filter type_debug
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: cloud| type_debug

- name: check if target host is cloud system
  set_fact:
    dummy: true
  failed_when: cloud == "true"

  

TASK [Print value of var "cloud"] **********************************************
ok: [host.domain.com] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cloud": false
}
TASK [Print value of var with filter type_debug] *******************************
ok: [uhost.domain.com] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cloud| type_debug": "bool"
}
  
TASK [check if target host is cloud system] ************************************
ok: [host.domain.com]
```

So far so good. For testing purposes, I would like to see the task fail on purpose by negating the check. I tried with

```
  failed_when: not cloud
```

and

```
  failed_when: cloud == "false"
```

but it always ends with "ok":

```
TASK [check if target host is cloud system] ************************************
ok: [host.domain.com]
```

Why isn't the check failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "so far so good", but your check is completely incorrect.

```
  failed_when: cloud == "true"
```

`cloud` is a boolean, so it will never be equal to the string `"true"`.

You make the same mistake when you attempt to compare to `"false"`; I cannot reproduce your issue with using `failed_when: not cloud` under ansible-core 2.11.5.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cloud: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Debug cloud
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: "{{ cloud }} / {{ cloud | type_debug }}"

        - name: check if target host is cloud system
          set_fact:
            dummy: true
          failed_when: not cloud

      rescue:
        - debug:
```

```
TASK [Debug cloud] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "False / bool"
}

TASK [check if target host is cloud system] ************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"dummy": true}, "changed": false, "failed_when_result": true}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

However, this is not how you should be creating a failure. You have two good options, the [fail](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html) action and the [assert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) action. I tend to prefer `assert`.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cloud: true
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Debug cloud
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: "{{ cloud }} / {{ cloud | type_debug }}"

        - name: check if target host is cloud system
          assert:
            # There are other ways to check this, but Jinja's built-in false test reads nicely 
            that: cloud is false

      rescue:
        - debug:
```

```
TASK [Debug cloud] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "True / bool"
}

TASK [check if target host is cloud system] ************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "cloud is false",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

Comment: Cool! In fact, using the assert module is much more concise then what I built before (plus it works...). Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge and anwering my question!